# range to array: shrink variant array to boolean array

Tags: excel, vba

Consider this code:

```
Dim array As Variant
array = Range("a1:a1000000").Value2
```

Knowing that the A column only contains boolean (1 or 0) numbers, what's the most efficient way to shrink the array converting its data type to boolean?

Comment: Write a loop and fill a second array.

Comment: There's nothing to gain to shrink the array. Each cell in your range (assuming they are all integers 0..1) will be stored in the array as a `Long` data type. [This excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/4717755) describes how and why this happens. Additionally, the [Microsoft documentation for the `Boolean` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa164500(v=office.10)) shows that it's stored as an integer anyway.

Comment: Much more valuable to *actually* shrink your array to the size that's actually needed, i.e. if the sheet has 8721 rows and you still populate an array with a million rows, *that* is where the gain is. Don't worry about data type sizes, your computer has more than enough memory to handle it.

Comment: @PeterT:  actually as I can see in the Locals window each cell is stored in Variant/Double type   :(

Comment: Ultimately you are the one who can determine the value to your application on shrinking the array size. The advice given here, especially by @TimWilliams and MattieuGuindon, can guide you to shrink the array as much as you may need. In the bad old days of limited memory and baud rates (if you needed to transmit the data), I'd shrink it to a bit array, so I'm glad memory is much cheaper now :)